# Is there away to determine the remaining amount of memory available in a windows process?

Tags: .net, windows

I have a WPF application which is obviously a windows process, I'm able to determine the allocated managed memory and importantly the total memory used (private working set).

Is there an accurate to detemine the remaining available memory for allocation by the process?

I'm interested in knowing when an OutOfMemory exception could be thrown.

Comment: I think any answer you obtain will probably be out of date before you can act on it. And remember, it's not just the *amount* of address space that's free that's important. If the address space is sufficiently fragmented, then an attempt to allocate a small amount of space may still fail.

Comment: I'm only looking for an indictative answer, but yes I would agreee it would be stale very quickly

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct way to it, but you can "probe" the remaining available memory using the [`MemoryFailPoint`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.memoryfailpoint.aspx) class. It will throw a `InsufficientMemoryException` if the requested memory is not available. You can then do a kind of "binary search" to get an approximation of the available memory.

Comment: I like the idea, get to have a class called Probe :)